# How to get the selected resource from the eventAdd callback?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-6

i'm testing fullcalendar with resource sheduler.
I'm able to add an event to the calendar by clicking on a row, but in the event received by `eventAdd` callback, there is no reference to the resource where I've clicked.

For example: let's assume a hotel planner, where each resource row represents a room. If I click on the 6th row, I can add the event but I don't know how to know the the clicked row was the 6th on the planner.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Clicking on a resource does not, by itself, trigger the `eventAdd` callback. It _does_ potentially trigger the `select` or `dateClick` callbacks, both of which will tell you which resource was clicked on ([here's a demo](https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJdoMGb)). If you still need further help beyond that, please show the code you're using as a [mre] of your issue, so we can understand more clearly. Thanks